# Python script with executeStreamCommand in Apache Nifi ? Import not found

Tags: apache-nifi

I try to use ExecuteStreamCommand processor in Apache Nifi in order to execute a simple Python Script.

Here is the python script:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
file = pd.read_json(sys.stdin)
file.to_json(sys.stdout)
```

Here is the processor configuration:
[image: Processor configuration]

I have the error:
[image: Error]

I don't know where I am wrong.

Comment: Command - should be `python`, and argument - path to py file.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s what you can do: Add the full path to the Python command in the Command Argument space, and provide the full path to the script under command arguments. This will work.